# How to check 404 page crash in webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to write a script for testing 404-page crashes using webdriver.I want webdriver to get to each link of a website and if 404 error is encountered then take a screenshot for the same.

It should work in looping.

Comment: To achieve that you need to write some code. Can you share your work please?

Comment: There's no point using Selenium for this. Just crawl the site and check the response codes. The 404 page will presumably always look the same, so who cares about taking a screenshot?

Comment: In similar thoughts with @Michael getting a screenshot of a 404 page would be of no value _All looks same_. Simply crawling the site and check the response codes must suffice.

Comment: This is pointless. You should not be testing for a fixed result from a dynamic source. Any URL that isn't defined in the web-app should cause a 404, and that can change any time the web-app or its content is expanded. The look and feel of the 404 page can also change, any time the UI designers so decide, or the designers of any package they are relying on, such as Prime Faces etc., and again you should certainly not be testing for a fixed result from a dynamic source.

Answer (score 0):

Add this check in script and pass the element locator(i.e.) which your are expecting on 404 page

```
 if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("value")).size() != 0) {
          customScreenshot(driver);
      }
```

Note :- you have to replace xpath in as per your element in above code

Add this function in your class :-

```
   public static void customScreenshot(WebDriver driver){
       try {
           File screenShot=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
           // extracting date for folder name.
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForFoldername = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//dd/MM/yyyy
           Date currentDate = new Date();
           String folderDateFormat = dateFormatForFoldername.format(currentDate);
           // extracting date and time for snapshot file
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
           String fileDateFormet = dateFormatForFileName.format(currentDate);
           String filefolder="./test-output"+"/Snap/"+folderDateFormat+"/";
           // Creating folders and files
           File screenshot = new File(filefolder+fileDateFormet+".jpeg");
           FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(screenshot.getPath()));
           } 
           catch (Exception ex) {
               System.err.println("Unable to capture screenshot...");
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
   }
```